# How do I save QR code scan results in listview?

Tags: java, android, listview, qr-code

In the barcode section, I read the barcodes. I want to save the scan results to the list view I created. I tried to do it by looking at many projects but I failed. Can you help me? I'm sorry if the question's been a little long.

```
public class BarcodeReaderFragment extends Fragment {

barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
    @Override
    public void release() {

    }

    @Override
    public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
        final SparseArray<Barcode> qrcode = detections.getDetectedItems();
        if (qrcode.size() != 0) {
            Intent my = new Intent(getActivity(),ResultActivity.class);
            my.putExtra("type", qrcode.valueAt(0));

            currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            String formattedDate = df.format(currentTime);
            String d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            System.out.println(formattedDate);

            //Add QR scan result to listview???
            //Add current time and date to listview???

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(qrcode.valueAt(0));
            SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("list",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            addhistory(sp,json);
            startActivity(my);
            getActivity().finish();
            barcodeDetector.release();
        }
    }
});

public void addhistory(SharedPreferences sp,String json){
    int x = sp.getInt("index",0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString(String.valueOf(x),json);
    int  y;
    y = x+1;
    editor.putInt("index",y);
    editor.commit();

}
```

**Item_Model**

```
public class Item_Model implements Serializable {

    private String result, date_time;

    public Item_Model(String result, String date_time) {
        this.result = result;
        this.date_time = date_time;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public String getDate_time() {
        return date_time;
    }
```

**ListView_Adapter**

```
public class ListView_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Item_Model> item_modelArrayList;
    private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;

    public ListView_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item_Model> item_modelArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.item_modelArrayList = item_modelArrayList;
        mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return item_modelArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
        public Item_Model getItem(int position) {
        return item_modelArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.Result = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.result);
            holder.Date_time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date_time);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.Result.setText(item_modelArrayList.get(position).getResult());
    holder.Date_time.setText(item_modelArrayList.get(position).getDate_time());


        /** Change background color of the selected items in list view  **/
        convertView
            .setBackgroundColor(mSelectedItemsIds.get(position) ? 0x48FF9800
                    : Color.TRANSPARENT);

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView Result, Date_time;
    }
```

**ThreeFragment**  In this episode, I'm watching Listview.

```
private ActionMode mActionMode;

private static View view;
private static ListView_Adapter adapter;
private static ListView listView;
//Action Mode for toolbar

private static ArrayList<Item_Model> item_models;

public ThreeFragment() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);
    populateListView();
    implementListViewClickListeners();




    return view;
}





//I don't know how to fill this section with detector results?
//Populate ListView with dummy data
private void populateListView() {
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    item_models = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 40; i++)
        item_models.add(new Item_Model("Result " + i, "Date-Time " + i));


    adapter = new ListView_Adapter(getActivity(), item_models);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}


//Implement item click and long click over listview
private void implementListViewClickListeners() {
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //If ActionMode not null select item
            if (mActionMode != null)
                onListItemSelect(position);
        }
    });
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Select item on long click
            onListItemSelect(position);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

//List item select method
private void onListItemSelect(int position) {
    adapter.toggleSelection(position);//Toggle the selection

    boolean hasCheckedItems = adapter.getSelectedCount() > 0;//Check if any items are already selected or not

    if (hasCheckedItems && mActionMode == null)
        // there are some selected items, start the actionMode
        mActionMode = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).startSupportActionMode(new Toolbar_ActionMode_Callback(getActivity(),adapter, item_models, true));
    else if (!hasCheckedItems && mActionMode != null)
        // there no selected items, finish the actionMode
        mActionMode.finish();

    if (mActionMode != null)
        //set action mode title on item selection
        mActionMode.setTitle(String.valueOf(adapter
                .getSelectedCount()) + " selected");


}

//Set action mode null after use
public void setNullToActionMode() {
    if (mActionMode != null)
        mActionMode = null;
}


//Delete selected rows
public void deleteRows() {
    SparseBooleanArray selected = adapter
            .getSelectedIds();//Get selected ids

    //Loop all selected ids
    for (int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        if (selected.valueAt(i)) {
            //If current id is selected remove the item via key
            item_models.remove(selected.keyAt(i));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//notify adapter

        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), selected.size() + " item deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//Show Toast
    mActionMode.finish();//Finish action mode after use

}
```

Comment: Post your code clearly, where do you get data list?

Comment: public class BarcodeReaderFragment extends Fragment

Comment: public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections)

Comment: Update your question with code

Comment: I get the data from the barcode fragment that I summarized at the top. The part where the Barcod result is transmitted // Add QR scan result to listview ???
                // Add current time and date to listview ??? as specified. Data Qr Scan result.

Comment: I'm new to Android. I'm trying to improve myself by dealing with something. It's a simple thing for you, but for me it's something I can't do for days. I hope you can help.

Comment: Feeling bad to hear that you are struggling for more days. According to your code, it seems you are trying to read QR using `BarcodeReaderFragment` which is added to `XxxActivity`. After getting the result from the QR detector you are trying to show the history of the QR result in a `list view` of `ThreeFragment` which is added to `ResultActivity`, right?. To understand your code clearly please add code for `addhistory(sp, json)` and `populateListView()` methods.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest. What I'm trying to do is, like you said. I added the history you said above. In this case, I can save the results to a normal list view. What I want to do is save it to the custom list view I created.

Comment: Put your code for `populateListView()` in `ThreeFragment`.

Comment: I've updated all three fragments.
The part I can't do is "private void populateListView ()"

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement in following steps:

1. Keep the `ResultActivity` as landing/parent activity.
2. Add `ThreeFragment` to the `ResultActivity`
3. Create a `BarcodeReaderActivity` and use `BarcodeDetector` in this activity directly (remove `BarcodeReaderFragment` for simplicity)
4. Start `BarcodeReaderActivity` with `startActivityForResult()` from `ThreeFragment` on your prefered interaction.
5. When you will get the result from `BarcodeDetector` then set the result to the `BarcodeReaderActivity` using `setResult("xxxxxx")` and `finish()` the activity.
6. In `ThreeFragment` you will get result in `onActivityResult()`
7. After getting the result, put it to the `list` and sent the list to `Adapter` and `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

## Update

Sorry to say that I can't change the whole project navigation and it will take too much time for me. You should ask a precise question here. I just checked your project and giving some feedback bellow. You have to code for this by yourself.

1. Use DB for list of data (QR scanned results)
2. For `ViewPager` you can find `visibility/invisibility` of a fragment by the following code:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed()) {
        //this fragment is visible now, do your expected code here
    } else {
        //this fragment is not visible now, do your expected code here
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(getUserVisibleHint()){
        //this fragment is visible now, do your expected code here
    } else {
        //this fragment is not visible now, do your expected code here
    }
}
```

Advice: Try to implement step by step, if any problem arise then try to solve the specific problem first.

Comment: It is very simple for you to do what you say, but it is impossible for me to do what you say with my current knowledge.

Comment: Push your current code to Github and give me the repository link, I will try to solve your problem when I will be available.

Comment: Thank you very much.I'll send the link after you install Github.

Comment: Like you said, I uploaded it to Github. I'd be very happy if you look when you're available. Thanks again.

Comment: My e-mail address: beytullah_zenginn@hotmail.com

Comment: @Beytullah don't worry! I will make it for you tomorrow, I was on vacation and currently having some emergency task.